# Amazon SQS Queue is not receiving messages

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-mws

Our Amazon SQS Queue is not receiving messages from Amazon MWS for the AnyOfferChanged notification.

We send a test notification and this is sent to the Queue and available when we get the notification.

We have set up two AWS accounts, we are using one AWS account to register the queue destination and create the subscription to AnyOfferChanged. The other AWS account gets the test notifications from our Queue successfully.

We can see that the competitors of the merchant have changed their price for a listing, but no notifications have been sent to us.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you've done most of the things correctly (registering destination and creating subscription).  Have you given Amazon themselves permission to write to the SQS queue?

1. On the SQS page in AWS Console, select the queue
2. In the pane that appears below, click on the Permissions tab
3. Click on the Edit pencil and give the Principal value "437568002678" for Amazon
4. Select some Actions (would depend on your use; I've used 'SendMessage' and 'GetQueueAttributes')
5. Save

That "Principal" value I got from [this PDF:](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/subscriptions/MWSSubscriptionsApiReference._V356512412_.pdf)

Hope that sorts it out!

Comment: Thanks. You've got back to me before Amazon have. Still waiting for their response in fact. I have set the Principle up with this value and subscribed to the notification. Not sure what to expect as confirmation, other than a flood of messages in the queue.

Comment: What is the meaning of "437568002678"? Each account must have its own, and not one for everyone.

Comment: [Description here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/subscriptions/Subscriptions_ReceivingNotifications.html#SQSQueue)